# Оптимальный код парсинга string в decimal

Tags: c#, json

Имею некий джейсон который десериализую в объект, одно из полей которого нужно спарсить в decimal

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using static System.Convert;
using static System.Globalization.CultureInfo;
using static System.Globalization.NumberStyles;

public class OpenOrder
{
   ...
   [JsonProperty("margin")]   
   public decimal margin;
}
```

но периодически пиходят данные в форматах (123,345 или 1.09E+30) то с точками, то с запятыми, то в экспоненциальном...

нашел вариант, но как-то он мне не по душе.

```
[JsonProperty("margin")]
private string Margin
{ 
  set { decimal.TryParse(value, Any, InvariantCulture, out margin); } 
}
public decimal margin;
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? И подскажет какую-то упрощенную конструкцию?

Comment: [Decimal is not converting exponential value ( jsonConverter from JSON to C#) - mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52178992/2881286)

Comment: Отказываемся работать с таким форматом. Проблема не на нашей стороне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это [известная проблема с разбором decimal из экспоненциальной формы](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1711), был даже [push с фиксом, но похоже его пока не включили в версию](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/1714).

---

Можно воспользоваться атрибутом [`JsonConstructor`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm), тогда не надо будет заводить отдельное поле:

```
public class OpenOrder {
    ...
    public decimal margin;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public OpenOrder(string margin) {
        decimal.TryParse(margin, Any, InvariantCulture, out this.margin);
    }
    ...
}
```

<sub>на основе ответа [@WarisSarwar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52178992/2881286)</sub>

---

Либо использовать [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
public class OpenOrder
{
    ...
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonExponentialConverter))]
    public decimal Margin { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

где `JsonExponentialConverter` может выглядеть так:

```
public class JsonExponentialConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        decimal d = 0;
        if (decimal.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
        {
            return d;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

<sub>перевод ответа [@er-shoaib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52178671/2881286)</sub>